# Download de arquivos não funciona

Tags: c#, asp.net

Como baixar um arquivo pelo navegador de um diretório no meu projeto?

Tentei da seguinte maneira, mas nada ocorre:

```
 string path = "C:\\test.txt";
        var file = new FileInfo(path);
        if (file.Exists)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ClearHeaders();
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
            Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            Response.Flush();
            Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);
            Response.End();
        }
```

debuguei e os valores vao tudo certinho, mas não baixa nada no navegador, como faço?

```
<system.web>
<!-- Autenticação-->
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="login" loginUrl="login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="1" defaultUrl="pagina.aspx" requireSSL="false"/>
</authentication>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="50000" />
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
```

Comment: Você está usando MVC por acaso?

Comment: Meu mvc é manual, nao uso o padrao da microsoft asp.net mvc, é web forms

Comment: testei em outro projeto meu codigo desde o inicio e funciona, o que pode ser?

Comment: @WarLock esse código é disparado por um controle dentro de um updatepanel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@WarLock, com o conhecimento que tenho sobre a sua aplicação (adquerido de outras perguntas suas), acredito que o seu problema não está no download em si, mas na mecanica do `UpdatePanel`.

Então aconselho você modificar ou adicionar o evento `ItemDataBound` ao seu `Repeater`, então registrar o Control para PostBack.

```
protected void <repeaterID>_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var btDownload = e.Item.FindControl("<buttonID>") as Button;
        this.<scriptManagerID>.RegisterPostBackControl(btDownload);
    }
}
```

Comment: é isso mesmo que vc falou, quando eu tiro o button do updatepanel, funciona, porem dessa sua forma nao consegui.

Answer (score 0):

Testei o seu código aqui e funciona normalmente.

Tente mudar o contentType, assim:

```
//Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
Response.ContentType = "application/force-download";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
```

Comment: coloquei e nada.

Comment: ele esta entrando, como mencionei no post eu debuguei.

Comment: nada de download no navegador ainda

Comment: Ja que vc falou que funcionou ai, mudei o titulo para ver se alguem descobre pq nao funciona.

Comment: ainda não consegui

Comment: testei em outro projeto meu codigo desde o inicio e funciona, o que pode ser?

Comment: Tenta comparar os arquivos `web.config` principalmente na seção `<system.webServer>`.

Comment: nao existe system.webserver, e sim system.web

Comment: postei o web config

Comment: Testei no pageload e funcionou

Comment: masn o meu evento nao funciona

Answer (score 0):

Estás com alguns problemas no código. Apesar de eu não ter experimentado, já tentas-te assim? Adaptei a ideia [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19079591).

```
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    System.IO.FileInfo Dfile = new System.IO.FileInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path));
    Response.TransmitFile(Dfile.FullName);
    HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Comment: da erro na linha:  System.IO. fala que o diretorio é físico e espera um virtual

Comment: Coloca só `System.IO.FileInfo Dfile = new System.IO.FileInfo(path);`

Comment: nada ainda, é estranho, nao aparece nenhum erro nem nada. no debug passa todos os passos. mas nao aparece download no navegador

Comment: Experimenta `Response.WriteFile(path);` em vez de `Response.TransmitFile(Dfile.FullName);`

Comment: não foi ainda...

Comment: testei em outro projeto meu codigo desde o inicio e funciona, o que pode ser?